# Getting the status of the [Ctrl] key when reading console input in Java on Unix-like systems

Tags: java, console-application

I am currently trying to write a small library for working with the Linux terminal in Java, and I need to create a method which would read the keyboard input in the non-blocking manner using `System.in`. To do this, the terminal should already be in the so-called "raw" or "non-canonical" mode, which I achieve successfully by using JNA and calling native `libc` functions `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()`.

I start by wrapping the `System.in` reader in a `BufferedReader`:

```
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Then I read the contents of the buffer into a `char[]` array and parse its contents:

```
    if (input.ready()) {
        char[] chars = new char[4]; // any valid key combination is max 4 characters long
        int result = input.read(chars, 0, 4);
        if (result == -1) {
            // EOF
            ...
        }
        if (result == 1) {
            // probably just a regular character
            ...
        }
        if (result == 2) {
            if (chars[0] == '\033' {
                // alt + char
                ...
            }
            if (chars[0] == '^') {
                // ctrl + char
                ...
            }
        }
        if (result == 3 || result == 4) {
            // some sort of special character -- cursor keys, <Home>, <End> etc.
            ...
        }
    }
    return null;
```

This system more or less works as expected *EXCEPT* it does not detect Ctrl+key combinations. (Alt+key combinations are handled just fine.)

I can check for individual Ctrl+key combinations by using the following code:

```
public char ctrlKey(char c) {
    return (char) (c & 0x1f); // shamelessly stolen from the curses library :-) 
}
```

Then in my code I can check:

```
   if (c == ctrlKey('x')) {
       // do stuff
   }
```

This also works, however this should be done on the client side if the client wants to implement e.g. GNU Readline-like key combinations. What I'd like to do is to return an instance of the following class which already has all the information that the client needs (`KeyType` is just an `enum` which lists all possible special keys):

```
public class KeyStroke {

    public final char c;

    public final boolean alt;

    public final boolean ctrl;

    public final KeyType type;

    public KeyStroke(char c, KeyType keyType, boolean ctrl, boolean alt) {
        this.c = c;
        this.alt = alt;
        this.ctrl = ctrl;
        this.type = keyType;
    }
}
```

Do I understand correctly that this is more or less impossible? (Unless I want to construct a giant `switch` case in my input parsing method and test for every possible Ctrl+key combination, which would be... stupid? inelegant?)

**Update**

I looked at [JNativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) as suggested by @DevilsHnd, and while it's probably nice for some applications, it has a hard dependency on X11, which means that it does not work in remote sessions over SSH, in the pure text mode (e.g. on a server installation without the graphical interface), or in Wayland.

Comment: Perhaps try using [JNativeHook](http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/).

Comment: @DevilsHnd doesn't look like it works in the actual text console or in Wayland :(

Comment: I would be very surprised if a terminal were capable of detecting this at all.  Terminals have never communicated modifier key state, as far as I know.  For example, I’m pretty sure terminal programs cannot distinguish between the user typing Ctrl-I and the user typing Tab.  Same for Ctrl-H and Backspace (or Delete, depending on stty settings).

Comment: Control characters are often _displayed_ (including echoed) as caret/uparrow-then-printable e.g. `^G` for bell, but they are NOT input that way. On input a control character is a single byte with value 0x00 to 0x1F or 0x7F. In now-rare 8-bit environments 0xA0 to 0xBF are also control characters, but usually can't be entered from a keyboard; these are called C1 set versus C0 set above. (In UTF-8, used on most Linux and forced in all Java 18 up, multiple bytes of 0x80 to 0xF4 encode all blocks other than ASCII.) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

As explained in the comments by @VGR and @dave_thompson_085, pressing Ctrl does not actually output a control character. The console might print `^C` when the user presses Ctrl+c, but this is done simply for the sake of visual feedback.

Instead, pressing Control modifies the value of the character that is output when the user presses other keys. So for example when the user presses Ctrl+c, the resulting character has value of 0x03 instead of 0x63, Ctrl+q outputs 0x11 instead of 0x71 etc.

The way it is handled in GNU Readline, ncurses and other libraries is very simple. If the character code is less than 32, they test for a few control characters (such as `\t`, `\r` and `\n`) and then simply add 96 to the character code to reconstruct what key was pressed together with Ctrl. I tested this approach and it 100% works:

```
if (ch < 32) {
    switch (ch) {
        case 0x00: // null
        case '\t': // Tab
        case '\r': // CR
        case '\n': // LF
        case 0x08: // Backspace
        case 0x1b: // ESC
        ...
        default:   key = (char) (ch + 96); 
    }
}
```

This can also be applied to Alt+Ctrl+key combinations. This would result in a 2-character input, the first character is always equal to 0x1b (or 27 in decimal, or '\033') but the second one should be tested in the same way as Ctrl+key.

I now feel that this question is not necessarily about Java, because any console application running in a Unix-like environment would face the same challenges regardless of the language it is written in (unless it is uses a library that does all the heavy lifting and presents the parsed and sanitized input to the said application).